# Ordenar DataFrame pela soma dos valores de um grupo

Tags: python, pandas, classificação, group-by

Eu tenho um Dataframe do tipo:

```
df = {'Column1': ['A', 'A', B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Column2': ['G1','G2','G1','G2','G1','G2'], 'Column3': ['1','2','4','9','6','4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Que aparece como:

```
Column1        Column2       Column3
   A              G1            1
   A              G2            2
   B              G1            4
   B              G2            9
   C              G1            6
   C              G2            4
```

Eu preciso agrupar e ordenar com base no total de cada letra da coluna 1 (A, B, C) para dar a seguinte saida:

```
               Column2       Column3
   B              G1            4
                  G2            9
   C              G1            6
                  G2            4
   A              G1            1
                  G2            2
```

Qual seria o comando?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma seria:

1. Definir ordem
2. Transformar coluna a ser ordenada em índice
3. Ordenar pelo índice baseado na ordem do item 1
4. Resetar o índice

### Criando base de teste

```
import pandas as pd

dados = {'Column1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Column2': ['G1','G2','G1','G2','G1','G2'], 'Column3': [1, 2, 4, 9, 6, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dados)
```

**Nota**: Em seu exemplo, faltava um `'` antes do primeiro `B`
**Nota**: Sua coluna 3 deveria ser números (não?) portanto, retirei os `'`

### Definindo ordem

```
order = df.groupby("Column1").sum().reset_index().sort_values("Column3", ascending=False)["Column1"].to_list()
```

Resultado:

```
['B', 'C', 'A']
```

### Ordenando dataframe baseado na ordem

```
df = df.set_index("Column1").loc[order].reset_index()
```

Para este caso demonstrado, o resultado é um dataframe (não um grupo)

```
  Column1 Column2  Column3
0       B      G1        4
1       B      G2        9
2       C      G1        6
3       C      G2        4
4       A      G1        1
5       A      G2        2
```